# Verilog register code bug - condition checks

Tags: module, verilog

I am testing a module for an 8-bit register, separately from the rest of my code. I am using ModelSim to set the values and then Run to see the results.
This module is supposed to have a binary number input, a clear bit, an enable bit, and an output.

```
module Register8bit(D, Clk, Clear, Enable, OutNum);
    input [7:0] D; //8 bit binary data
    input Clk;       //Clock
    input Clear;     //Clear bit
    input Enable;    //Enable bit
    output reg [7:0] OutNum;

always @(posedge Clk)
begin
    if (Enable)
        begin
            if (Clear)
                OutNum <= 8'b00000000;
            else
                OutNum <= D;
        end
end
endmodule
```

Here is the output I am expecting (in this order), with D = 10001111 and Clk = 1.

```
Steps    CLR    Enable    OutNum
1        0      0         xxxxxxxx (initially undefined)
2        0      1         10001111 (input data is used)
3        1      0         10001111 (because write-protection)
4        1      1         00000000 (Clear and Enable are true, so set to 0)
5        0      1         10001111 (Clear is false and Enable is true, so use input data)
```

The first step works, but the second one does not (so the rest don't work either). Specifically, OutNum stays undefined on the second step. Updating OutNum with the input data does work in the first step if Enable is true.

How should I fix this module?

Test bench code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module test_register;

//inputs
reg [7:0] D;
reg Clk;
reg Clear;
reg Enable;

//outputs
reg [7:0] OutNum;

//instantiate
Register8bit uut(
    .D(D),
    .Clk(Clk),
    .Clear(Clear),
    .Enable(Enable)
);

initial begin
    D = 10001111;
    Clk = 1;

    //step 1
    #100;
    Clear = 0;
    Enable = 0;
    #100;

    //step 2
    Clear = 0;
    Enable = 1;
    #100;

    //step 3
    Clear = 1;
    Enable = 0;
    #100;

    //step 4
    Clear = 1;
    Enable = 1;
    #100;

    //step 5
    Clear = 0;
    Enable = 1;
    #100;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle your `Clk` signal many times.  Your code just sets it to 1, then leaves it at 1 for the whole sim.

```
module test_register;

//inputs
reg [7:0] D;
reg Clk;
reg Clear;
reg Enable;

//outputs
reg [7:0] OutNum;

//instantiate
Register8bit uut(
    .OutNum  (OutNum),  // <---- added missing output
    .D(D),
    .Clk(Clk),
    .Clear(Clear),
    .Enable(Enable)
);

always #50 Clk = ~Clk;

always @(negedge Clk) begin
    $display($time, " clr=%b en=%b D=%b OutNum=%b", Clear, Enable, D, OutNum);
end

initial begin
    D = 'b10001111; // <---- use 'b
    Clk = 1;

    #50;

    //step 1
    #100;
    Clear = 0;
    Enable = 0;
    #100;

    //step 2
    Clear = 0;
    Enable = 1;
    #100;

    //step 3
    Clear = 1;
    Enable = 0;
    #100;

    //step 4
    Clear = 1;
    Enable = 1;
    #100;

    //step 5
    Clear = 0;
    Enable = 1;
    #100;
    #500 $finish;
end
endmodule

/*

Prints out:

                  50 clr=x en=x D=10001111 OutNum=xxxxxxxx
                 150 clr=0 en=0 D=10001111 OutNum=xxxxxxxx
                 250 clr=0 en=1 D=10001111 OutNum=xxxxxxxx
                 350 clr=1 en=0 D=10001111 OutNum=10001111
                 450 clr=1 en=1 D=10001111 OutNum=10001111
                 550 clr=0 en=1 D=10001111 OutNum=00000000
                 650 clr=0 en=1 D=10001111 OutNum=10001111
                 750 clr=0 en=1 D=10001111 OutNum=10001111
                 850 clr=0 en=1 D=10001111 OutNum=10001111
                 950 clr=0 en=1 D=10001111 OutNum=10001111
                1050 clr=0 en=1 D=10001111 OutNum=10001111

*/
```